# Can Someone Tell Me Where This Scene is From?

Tags: marvel, x-men

I recently found this online, and was wondering what it was from. Due to the content, it appears to be part of one of the novelizations of the first *X-Men* movie, but I can't tell for certain.

Here is the link:
https://matthewjagerdailystar.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/02020821.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [*X-Men*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0440417120) by Lara Bergen. It is the book adaptation of the first movie.

You can see a snippet of the content by searching Google Books for ["safe for man and mutant"](https://books.google.com/books?id=F8XrAAAAMAAJ&q="safe+for+man+and+mutant")